# HttpWebResponse returns Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in Windows 10 Redstone

Tags: c#, windows, cisco

While testing some of our applications for compatibility with Windows 10 (specifically on the preview to make sure everything works on the anniversary update due out next month) we found that our Call Center application no longer connects. Current windows preview build is 14361.

We get a WebException stating: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I looked up some other similar answers here, saying to force TLS1.2, or to enable tracing to see if a HTTP error is being generated.

Below is the trace results:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11344] Exiting Socket#60270212::Receive()  -> Int32#4383
System.Net Information: 0 : [11344] InitializeSecurityContext(credential =     System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 15eda00:a93eed8, targetName = servernameredacted, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [11344] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=InternalError).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11344] Socket#60270212::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [11344] Exception in HttpWebRequest#14000148:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [11344] Exception in HttpWebRequest#14000148::GetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
public static string PerformAPIOperation(HTTPOperation operation, string uriP2, string xmlData, string postData = "")
    {

        //test to fix issue in win10ani
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        try
        {
            if (uriP2.ToLower().Contains("/finesse/api/"))
            {
                //trim off the parts we are already expecting
                uriP2 = uriP2.Split(new string[] { "/finesse/api/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
            }
            //create webrequest, using https if set
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create((mainSettings.useHTTPS) ? string.Format(connectURIHTTPS, mainSettings.FQDN, uriP2) : string.Format(connectURIHTTP, mainSettings.FQDN, uriP2)) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            request.Method = operation.ToString();

            if (postData != string.Empty)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + postData);
            }

            if (operation != HTTPOperation.GET)
            {
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    char[] reqData = xmlData.ToCharArray();
                    byte[] byteStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqData);

                    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                    stream.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);
                }
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is WebException)
            {
                HttpWebResponse resp2 = ((WebException)ex).Response as HttpWebResponse;
                string response = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp2.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                using (_sw = new StreamWriter(mainSettings.GetSaveLocation(false) + @"WEBLOGGING\error.log", true))
                {
                    _sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                    _sw.WriteLine(response);
                    _sw.WriteLine();
                }

                return response;
            }
            else return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `or` together all the supported protocols for `SecurityProtocol`, if it works remove them one by one to identify the culprit.  That trace log looks incomplete, have you setup the maximum verbosity level?  Have you examined a request with a protocol aware packet monitor like WireShark?

Comment: Tried that, still fails even with all protocols or'd together. Max verbosity was turned on, everything I left out was the raw HTTP data, which was just gibberish other than the server name floating in there a few times. Also, the website version of the Call Center will not open in Internet Explorer or MS Edge.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ will tell you the supported protocols and cipher suites

Comment: It's an internal site, and requires a port connection other than 443, so that site wouldn't be helpful. This all worked on Windows 7, 8, and non-redstone Windows 10.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking for in all this Wireshark data. It's all encrypted, but I don't see any protocol names in any of the data.